# Reverseproxy for WS using IIS

Tags: iis, websocket, reverse-proxy

I have been searching all day long, but I don't have a clue how to solve this problem. I know there are similar questions here, but none seems to word.

I have an IIS server running on https://hostname.xy I deliver html and JS content from there and I have already configured a reverseproxy for SPA.

Now I am running a tomcat-server on port 7000 on the same server. The tomcat server accepts ws://..../.. requests.

All I want to do is communicating with that server. Requests get blocked because of mixed content. So I tried adding ssl to my tomcat server which is blocked because of a self signed certificate.
Is it possible to configure a reverse proxy that redirects all wss traffic to ws on a specific port? Could you share the specific rule from the web configuration in the IIS?

I tried next too many other rules this one here:

```
<rule name="WS reverse proxy" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="wss://myhostname.de/*" />     
    <action type="Rewrite" url="ws://127.0.0.1:7000/chat" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
</rule>
```

Comment: What exactly didn't work for you? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

Comment: The guides only show http redirects and they never show ws redirects. Unless http redirect magically implies ws redirects, I have no idea what to do.

Comment: @user1497119 Did you manage to solve this? I have a similar situation where I have a websocket server program listening on port 5004 and want IIS to redirect websocket requests to it.

Comment: @Magnus No, I did not solve this. I've ended up using SSE instead. To use websockets over https, you'll probably need a real certificate. Don't even waste time on self-signed certificates.